# Shinobi Charts selected point highlighting

Tags: shinobi

I have a SChartLineSeries and when I select a point, the selectedPointStyle doesn't seem to get applied.

Here's my code:

```
-(SChartSeries*)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart seriesAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
   SChartLineSeries* lineSeries = [[SChartLineSeries alloc] init];

   lineSeries.selectionMode = SChartSelectionPoint;

   SChartLineSeriesStyle *style = [SChartLineSeriesStyle new];
   style.pointStyle = [SChartPointStyle new];
   style.pointStyle.showPoints = YES;
   style.pointStyle.color = [UIColor whiteColor];
   style.pointStyle.radius = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
   //style.pointStyle.innerRadius = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
   style.selectedPointStyle.color = [UIColor orangeColor];
   style.selectedPointStyle.radius = [NSNumber numberWithInt:15];

   [lineSeries setStyle:style];
   //[lineSeries setSelectedStyle:style];
}
```

Please help. We're in a crunch time. Also, if I have to customize to show a dashed line, is it possible to do so in Shinobi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to set properties on the `selectedPointStyle` property, which is `nil` by default. In the same way that you created a new `SChartPointStyle` object for the `pointStyle` property, you need to create one for the `selectedPointStyle` property.

Update your code to the following and you should observe the selection effect that you're after:

```
- (SChartSeries*)sChart:(ShinobiChart *)chart seriesAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
   SChartLineSeries* lineSeries = [[SChartLineSeries alloc] init];

   lineSeries.selectionMode = SChartSelectionPoint;

   SChartLineSeriesStyle *style = [SChartLineSeriesStyle new];
   style.pointStyle = [SChartPointStyle new];
   style.pointStyle.showPoints = YES;
   style.pointStyle.color = [UIColor whiteColor];
   style.pointStyle.radius = @(5);

   style.selectedPointStyle = [SChartPointStyle new];
   style.selectedPointStyle.showPoints = YES;
   style.selectedPointStyle.color = [UIColor orangeColor];
   style.selectedPointStyle.radius = @(15);

   [lineSeries setStyle:style];
   return lineSeries;
}
```

In answer to your other question, dashed lines are not currently supported as part of ShinobiCharts.

Comment: That worked beautifully, thanks so much. Another question, I have two line series and how do I make points on both series selected at the same time? Basically, my chart has 2 y values sharing the same x value and I'm representing them as two series. I want to display both points as selected for a given X Value.

Comment: That's great. You should post your 2nd question as a new question so that it's easier for other people to find in future. And if you accept this answer then others will realise that it works :)

Comment: I was doing exactly the same thing as you suggested Sam. The problem it wasn't working because the selected point style is nil by default and needed to be initialized.